# Merging DataFrames as different dtypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframes into one by matching a column (time). I have two dataframes as illustrated below.

DataFrame 1

```
                              Händelse       Time  Diesel (l)
28   Bränslenivåökning vid stillastående  20210809      779942
55   Bränslenivåökning vid stillastående  20210810      780215
70   Bränslenivåökning vid stillastående  20210811      780448
87   Bränslenivåökning vid stillastående  20210812      780819
106  Bränslenivåökning vid stillastående  20210813      781037
```

DataFrame 2

```
            Time   Tankad mängd diesel
0      20Datum                     x
208   20141124                293.54
212   20141124                   295
215   20141125                 296.4
218   20141126                   286
221   20141126                287.09
```

As you can see, these two dataframes have a similar column "time". I want these two to merge where the dates are identical (the dates in the illustration are just a fraction of the dates, that's why there are no identical dates). However, I currently have this code:

```
import os
from numpy import empty, percentile
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from tkinter import Tk     # from tkinter import Tk for Python 3.x
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import logging
import sys
import pathlib
from datetime import date, datetime

Tk().withdraw()
filepathname1 = askopenfilename()
filepathname2 = askopenfilename()

print("You have chosen to mix", filepathname1, "and", filepathname2)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", 4)

df1 = pd.read_excel(filepathname1, 'CWA107 Event', na_values=['NA'], skiprows=1, usecols="A, B, F")

df2 = pd.read_excel(filepathname2, na_values=['NA'], skiprows=1, usecols=['Tankad mängd diesel', 'Unnamed: 3']
)

df2.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 3': 'Tid'}, inplace=True)

df2

df2.dropna(inplace=True)

for col in df1.columns:
    print(col)
for col in df2.columns:
    print(col)

df1['Tid'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Tid']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)


df1.dropna(inplace=True)

df1filt = df1[(df1['Händelse'] == "Bränslenivåökning vid stillastående")]

print(df1filt)
df2filt = df2[(df2['Tankad mängd diesel'] != pd.NA)]

df2filt['Tid'] = '20' + df2filt['Tid'].astype(str)

print(df2filt)

#merged_df = df1filt.merge(df2filt, on='Tid')
#print(merged_df)

print("Antal tankningar:", len(df1filt))

input()
```

As you can see I have tried merging the two columns by using

```
#merged_df = df1filt.merge(df2filt, on='Tid')
#print(merged_df)
```

And when I run my code using this code I get the error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on int32 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

I have also tried converting the strings to integers which do not work because of the line with 20Datum in *dataframe 2*.

Expected output:

```
                              Händelse       Time  Diesel (l)  Tankad mängd diesel
28   Bränslenivåökning vid stillastående  20210809      779942          153435
55   Bränslenivåökning vid stillastående  20210810      780215          434452
70   Bränslenivåökning vid stillastående  20210811      780448          246346
87   Bränslenivåökning vid stillastående  20210812      780819          974252
106  Bränslenivåökning vid stillastående  20210813      781037          567565
```

Hopefully this is enough information. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if problem is with zero row, you could simply drop it and try to merge again (if there is no certain reason you need this row):

```
df2filt = df2filt.drop(df2filt.index[0])
```

or

```
df2filt.drop(df2filt.index[0], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hmm now I unfortunately get the error:

`numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U2'), dtype('int32')) -> None`

Comment: After you add '20' to time column in df2 and convert it to string, convert it to the same type as df1.
Btw, try to convert both to 'int64', since just 'int' is not a pandas data type.

Comment: How do you suggest I procced? I currently have this code: 

`df2filt.drop(df2filt.index[0], inplace=True)
df2filt['Tid'] = '20' + df2filt['Tid'].astype(int64)
df1 = pd.DataFrame.astype(int64)`

Comment: Try like this maybe:

`df2filt.drop(df2filt.index[0], inplace=True)
df2filt['Tid'] = '20' + df2filt['Tid']
df2filt['Tid'] = df2filt['Tid'].astype(int64)
df1 = pd.to_datetime(df1['Tid']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int64)`

then merge.

Comment: Solved last error, but now I got:

`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: Sorry, lost casting of original value of df2filt['Tid'] to string for concatenating, rewrite the line like you had before:
`df2filt['Tid'] = '20' + df2filt['Tid'].astype(str)`
or `df2filt['Tid'] = '20' + df2filt['Tid'].astype(object)`

Comment: Alright, I should probably change the df1 dtype to str as well?

Comment: Now I got: 

`df2filt.drop(df2filt.index[0], inplace=True) 
df2filt['Tid'] = '20' + df2filt['Tid'].astype(str) 
df1 = pd.to_datetime(df1['Tid']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int64)
merged_df = df1filt.merge(df2filt, on='Tid')
print(merged_df)`

Comment: @LeopoldWahlbeck well I guess you could cast to either type, though they should be the same for both columns df1filt['Tid'] and df2filt['Tid'].

Comment: Fixed problem by having it as: 
`df1['Tid'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Tid']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(str)
df1.dropna(inplace=True)
df1filt = df1[(df1['Händelse'] == "Bränslenivåökning vid stillastående")]
df2filt = df2[(df2['Tankad mängd diesel'] != pd.NA)]
df2filt.drop(df2filt.index[0], inplace=True) 
df2filt['Tid'] = '20' + df2filt['Tid'].astype(str) 
merged_df = df1filt.merge(df2filt, on='Tid')
print(merged_df)`

The data is stored in the same dataframe but not on the same rows...
When I print the merged dataframe, it first prints 1 and then 2 under. (Doesnt really "merge")

Comment: Also, the time row in second df is not printed. Maybe this could be because only the dates merge? And not other data on the same row.

Comment: Try changing the merge mode:
`merged_df = df1filt.merge(df2filt, on='Tid', how='outer')`

Comment: This made the dataframes longer and made values with NaN show up. Did also not line them up next to each other.  Maybe it tries to merge on top of the other dataframe?

Comment: Hey! Tried to write it into a excel file and then they lined up! Thank you for your help!